# Create virtual webcam with PushSource

Tags: c++, windows, video, camera, directshow

I try to modify the pushsource example in directshow to accept bytestream from external program.

For the moment the pushsource program takes bitmap images and send it to the virtual webcam.

How could I modify to make it accept bytestream?

Edit:

I try to modify the PushSource program like this:

```
    // Filter setup data


const AMOVIESETUP_MEDIATYPE sudOpPinTypes2[] =
{
    {
    &MEDIATYPE_Video,       // Major type
    &MEDIASUBTYPE_NULL      // Minor type
    }
};


const AMOVIESETUP_PIN sudOutputPinBitmap2[] =
{
    { L"Input", FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, &CLSID_NULL, NULL, 1, &sudOpPinTypes2[0] },
    { L"Output", FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, &CLSID_NULL, NULL, 1, &sudOpPinTypes2[0] }
};



const AMOVIESETUP_FILTER sudPushSourceBitmap2 =
{
    &CLSID_PushSourceBitmap,// Filter CLSID
    g_wszPushBitmap,        // String name
    MERIT_DO_NOT_USE,       // Filter merit
    2,                      // Number pins
    sudOutputPinBitmap2     // Pin details
};






const AMOVIESETUP_PIN sudOutputPinDesktop = 
{
    L"Output",      // Obsolete, not used.
    FALSE,          // Is this pin rendered?
    TRUE,           // Is it an output pin?
    FALSE,          // Can the filter create zero instances?
    FALSE,          // Does the filter create multiple instances?
    &CLSID_NULL,    // Obsolete.
    NULL,           // Obsolete.
    1,              // Number of media types.
    &sudOpPinTypes  // Pointer to media types.
};

const AMOVIESETUP_FILTER sudPushSourceDesktop =
{
    &CLSID_PushSourceDesktop,// Filter CLSID
    g_wszPushDesktop,       // String name
    MERIT_DO_NOT_USE,       // Filter merit
    1,                      // Number pins
    &sudOutputPinDesktop    // Pin details
};


// List of class IDs and creator functions for the class factory. This
// provides the link between the OLE entry point in the DLL and an object
// being created. The class factory will call the static CreateInstance.
// We provide a set of filters in this one DLL.

CFactoryTemplate g_Templates[3] = 
{
    { 
      g_wszPushBitmap2,                // Name
      &CLSID_PushSourceBitmap,        // CLSID
      CPushSourceBitmap::CreateInstance,  // Method to create an instance of MyComponent
      NULL,                           // Initialization function
      &sudPushSourceBitmap2            // Set-up information (for filters)
    }   
};
```

When I modify the name of the webcam I can see the modification in GraphStudio but I still have only one output. No input is shown.